# Android how to make localization to range languages?

Tags: android, localization

I have three languages on my app: English, Russian, Spanish being English the default language.

Now I want to use the Russian language in some other countries in like: Ukraine and Belarus.

It's possible to use the russian language file the countrys that I mentioned or it's mandatory to create separated files for each one of them?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use same Russian translations for all three countries just add:

```
res/values-ru/
```

folder, and place strings.xml translation file in it with general Russian translations, it will display the same text for all Russian variants.

If you want to use different syntax, as I guess Russian is not 100% the same in all three countries create:

```
res/values-ru/     /* General Russian */
res/values-ru-rRU/ /* Russian Russian */
res/values-ru-rUA/ /* Ukrainian Russian */
res/values-ru-rBY/ /* Belorussian Russian */
```

folders, and place strings.xml translation file in each of them with localised translations. It will show translations to user based on their localised setting on the device: for Ukrainian, Belorussian, and Russian it will display the respective translation. For any other Russian region it will display the content from values-ru/

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a strings.xml file for each language and add it into a folder called values-es, values-de etc.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: You need to follow format for same language with different countries/regions.

For only locales
values-[locale]

For only locales with regions
values-[locale]-r[region]

In Your case
values-ru
values-ru-rRU
values-ru-rUA
values-ru-rBY

Comment: @KeyurAndroid Thank you for this info! Did not know it!

Comment: You try this.
Thanks Pavlos

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow format for same language with different countries/regions. 
For only locales 
values-[locale]

For only locales with regions
values-[locale]-r[region]

In Your case 
values-ru,
values-ru-rRU, 
values-ru-rUA,
values-ru-rBY,